# phonegap submit form, how to send to my email

Tags: forms, cordova

I am building simple phonegap android app.

i make simple html form with few input fields (Name, Last name, Question).
I want that when user fill input fields (Name, Last name, Question) and click Submit to send to my email address. Just that.

Do you have any idea how to do that with phonegap?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily by using php or .net (as your selection) with AJAX Call
Just Create One HTML page which display form to User for filling up data and send it.

Here I saw you how I done with PHP (Use phpmailer. for more, visit : http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail)

**HTML Form**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="#!" method="post">
                <input type = "text" name="cname" />
                <input type = "number" name="cnumber" />
                <input type = "email" name="cemail" />

                <input type = "submit" value="Submit" onclick="UpdateRecord()" />
            </form>
            <script>
                function UpdateRecord()
                  {
                      // Social Links
                      GolbalURL = "http://www.yourserverpathtophpfile.com";

                      var cname = $("[name='cname']").val();
                      var cnumber = $("[name='cnumber']").val();
                      var cemail = $("[name='cemail']").val();

                      jQuery.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: GolbalURL+"sendemail.php",

                       data: "cname="+ cname+"& cnumber="+ cnumber+"& cemail="+ cemail,
                       dataType: "html",      
                       cache: false,
                       success: function(response)
                       {
                         alert("Email Sent");
                       }
                     });
                 }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Sendmail.php**

```
    <?php
        $cname = $_REQUEST['cname'];
        $cnumber = $_REQUEST['cnumber'];
        $cemail = $_REQUEST['cemail'];

        require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"


        $body = "Name : ".$cname."Number : ".$cnumber."Email : ".$cemail;


        $mail->SetFrom($cemail, $cname);

        $address = "youremail@id.com";
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "Your Name");

        $mail->Subject    = "Your Subject";

        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

        $mail->MsgHTML($body);


        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          echo "Message sent!";
        }
    ?>
```

Do not forgot to upload your dynamic files to server and give it permissions. Or You can also call device's default mail application from code, check [PHONEGAP EMAIL COMPOSER](http://www.javahabit.com/2012/09/23/how-to-send-email-in-phonegap-android-using-a-gmail-account/)

**GIT Link Of Email Compo.**

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/172605ee12e58d5e5809e4e031b3b96cead143ac/README.md

Comment: Good example Shivam, thank you. But i have problem with CORS. Do you have this example in jsonp? I try to enable corse in my php file, but always say Cross-Origin Request Blocked. So if you have example with jsonp it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: @user3788491 I face same error while I try in browser, but after start browser by disable security, It works, and For JSONP, I'll try and check example and get back to you soon

Comment: Hello Shivam. If you have time it would be fantastic to send example with jasonp. Thank you very much.

Comment: bots and humans will find your api and send spam emails. needs auth or captcha that way.

Comment: @ekerner Yes, you are right. This is just for a basic. but for production, we need auth or captha.

Comment: Why not just use cordova-plugin-sms ?
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms
Possible disadvantage is that the user pays for the msg.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using ***Cordova EmailComposer Plugin*** for **Android** . Add this function on your submit button click. For installation follow these steps .

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

```
function emailComposer(){    

  window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable(
    function (isAvailable) {
      if(isAvailable){
            window.plugin.email.open({
                to:      [''],
                cc:      [''],
                bcc:     [''],
                subject: '',
                body:    ''
            });         
      }else{
          alert('Service is not available');
      }
    }
  );

}


**JQUERY - CALL PHP SCRIPT TO POST DATA**  

var ajax_call = serviceURL;
var form_data = $('#form').serialize();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ajax_call,
   data: form_data,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
    //called when successful

   },
   error: function(e) {
      //called when there is an error
   //console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

[Examples](http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-post/index.php)

Comment: i read that jsonp cannot send post request. How can i send data from my form to my server. I am building phonegap application, so i need to enable cross-origin policy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins to compose emails, but it won't send it automatically. You really need to use a back end service to handle this for you. You can setup your own using any app language (PHP, ColdFusion, etc), or consider a service like WuFoo perhaps.